# Show a message after sending a file to download

Tags: c#, asp.net, response, httpresponse, httpwebresponse

I want to update something on my aspx page, after I send a file to be downloaded. (Some error messages shown before.). I believe it's not possible, but would you provide me a solution?

Here is the code to send the file to download:

```
  Response.ContentType = "Application/zip";
  Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + e.CommandArgument);
  Response.BinaryWrite(fileStream.ToArray());
  Response.Flush();
  Response.Close();
  Response.End();
```

Editing to clarify: I also believe that there is no logical solution. However, there could be a Javascript trick which I am not aware of.

Comment: Response.Write("The file has been sent to you");

Comment: @inquisitive_mind He is already writing response with the file. What he means is he want to update the page as well. He cannot response the file and the updated page at the same time.

Comment: you need to use javascript, make an ajax call and update your page in success function

Comment: Exactly, there is no logical solution. However, there could be a Javascript trick which I am not aware of.

Answer (score 1):

That's the most simple way I can imagine.

```
<a href="Default.aspx?download=1"
    onclick="javascript:document.write('the file was downloaded');" >
    Click here to Download
</a>
```

In my code behind I have

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(Request["download"]=="1")
    {
        try
        {
            Response.ContentType = "html/text";
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=file.txt");
            Response.Write("content of the file");
            Response.Flush();
            Response.Close();
            Response.End();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //An error occurred
            Response.Redirect("Error.aspx");
        }
    }
}
```

Since it's just a link, if the file is not found the browser will display "not found". If there's an error at server side then redirect to error page. If you want a more elaborated solution I'd suggest using XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: Thanks, nice solution. My button is an asp.net button actually, to be honest I want to remove some error messages shown before. I just didn't want to add confusing details. I will edit the post again ad add it.

Comment: For an asp button there's an attribute called OnClientClick. You can put your javascript there.