# execute javascript after download a file (RegisterStartupScript)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, css

I want to execute a RegisterStartupScript calling a Javascript function after certain processes happen in my code behind. It is basically a Loading loop decoration made in CSS3. I show it (with javascript) on buttons clientclick, when I know the process will take a while and I hide it when the process is finished. Everything works fine, but now I have a process in Which I download a file using another empty webform using response.redirect. The file is downloaded fine, but the RegisterStartupScript call does not work. I understand the response is the problem, but nor I need to work in a workaround to solve this (I do not want to change the whole way, cause it is implemented in many other pages and processes. I wil provide the related code (not all), in case you can give me a direct way to solve it.

Javascript

```
function LoadingLoopOn()
{
    $('#outerAlignId').addClass("outerAlign");
    $('#middleAlignId').addClass("middleAlign");
    $('#innerAlignId').addClass("innerAlign");
    $('#OutterCircleId').addClass("OutterCircle");
    $('#InnerCircleId').addClass("InnerCircle");
    $('#Loadinglbl').addClass("LoadingLabelStyle");
}

function LoadingLoopOff()
{
    $('#outerAlignId').removeClass("outerAlign");
    $('#middleAlignId').removeClass("middleAlign");
    $('#innerAlignId').removeClass("innerAlign");
    $('#OutterCircleId').removeClass("OutterCircle");
    $('#InnerCircleId').removeClass("InnerCircle");
    $('#Loadinglbl').removeClass("LoadingLabelStyle");
}
```

HTML (it is on the master page, to be able to used it in every webform)

```
<asp:Panel ID="outerAlignId" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" CssClass="outerAlign">
    <div id="middleAlignId" class="middleAlign">
        <div id="innerAlignId" class="innerAlign">
            <div id="OutterCircleId" class="OutterCircle"></div>
            <div id="InnerCircleId" class="InnerCircle"></div>
            <asp:Label ID="Loadinglbl" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Text="Loading..." CssClass="LoadingLabelStyle"></asp:Label>
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

HTML Button Sample Where I want to used it

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ExportExId" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" OnClientClick="LoadingLoopOn();"  OnClick="ExportExId_Click" CssClass="..." ImageUrl="..." />
```

And the CS# Code behind

```
    protected void ExportExId_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        //...
        //Many code and DB treatment goes here, to finally get a temporally Excel file in the server
        //..

        //I call the page with the file name and path
        Response.Redirect(String.Format("DownloadForm.aspx?FileName={0}&Path={1}", fileExported.Name, "Temp" + UserName));

        //This piece of code must be excuted in its webform after the redirect (once ee finished)
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "LoadingLoopOff", "LoadingLoopOff();", true);

    }
```

As I marked in my comment, A possible solution could be AJAX. Make an ajax call to force a page update and then the function would be processed (on the load), or directly call the function through this ajax call. The problem is that I do not know how to uise AJAX in this case...

Many thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show a message after sending a file to download](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38617422/show-a-message-after-sending-a-file-to-download)

Comment: @VDWWD, Htanks for your comment. I am afraid is not hte same.He is trying to update something in the aspx page. I am trying to call a javascript function with RegisterStartupScript. I believe I cannot response to other aspx and then include an instruction in the same one, even if its a download file frame. One possible solution is doing it with ajax call after the response, but I have no idea how to do it...